# Assymptotic time complexity of this algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

I would like to know the time complexity of the following algorithm. At first glance the time complexity looks to be O(n^5) and that is what is mentioned in majority of the sites i have seen on the internet. But a careful analysis seems to give a different answer, here is the code:

```
public void fun(int n)
{
   int i,j,k,sum=0;
   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
       for(j=0;j<i*i;j++)
       {
            if(j%i==0)
            {
                for(k=0;k<j;k++)
                sum++;
            }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Well, if `i < j` what's `i % j` ?

Comment: @chill sorry, that was a typo... its j%i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `j%i c== 0` will yield `true`  `O(i)` times (for each distinct `i`) - thus the inner loop will repeat itself `O(i)` times in each "outer" iteration.

Thus the complexity is `O(n*n^2 + n*n^3) = O(n^4)`

**Explanation:**

`O(n*n^2)` is for the "middle loop" which repeats itself regardless of the evaluation of the if condition. It is `O(n^3)` since you get: `1 + 4 + 9 + 16 + ... + n^2` which is a [sum of squares](http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/mathematics/series/sumNaturalSquares.htm) and is `O(n^3)`.

`O(n*n^3)` is a bit trickier:

For each `i`, each inner loop repeats `i` times, so for each `i` you get:
`i + 2i + 3i + ... + (i-1)i` total repeats of the inner loop. It is easy to see that it is in fact `i(1 + 2 + ... + i-1)` which is `O(i^3)`.

Now, we can see that since it happens for each `i` - the total complexity will be (not being formal, just intuitive): `O(1^3) + O(2^3) + ... + O(n^3)` which is `O(n^4)` from [sum of cubed series](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_of_Sequence_of_Cubes)

**Conclusion:**

Though cold analysis might have shown `O(n^5)` - since the inner loop does not repeat itself for each iteration of the middle loop - **the total complexity is `O(n^4)`**